# Get the sum of the numbers from int array satisfying given condition with a single lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda

I don't know if I'm missing something simple, I have this working example:

```
    int[] x = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7};

    int[] arrayToUse = x.Where(i => i > 4).ToArray<int>();
    int sum = arrayToUse.Sum();

    Console.WriteLine(sum.ToString());
```

I'm wondering - is there a way to combine those two :

```
int[] arrayToUse = x.Where(i => i > 4).ToArray<int>();
int sum = arrayToUse.Sum();
```

in order to get one expression that will return the sum right away?

Comment: You can in fact combine all four into a single expression `Console.WriteLine(new int[] {1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7}.Where(i => i > 4).Sum());`

Comment: @Servy, this should be an answer

Comment: @GarryVass Technically he did specify just those two statements, not all four.

Comment: @Servy Well for that matter, it could be reduced to `Console.WriteLine(18)`.

Comment: Yeah, it's only for those two statements. I was wondering if I could perform comparison and mathematical operations in one expression. For some reason `VS2012` gave me an error when I tried `.Sum();` but it seems that it was due to something else.

Comment: @p.s.w.g Note however that it will break if the laws of arithmetic is changed in a future version of the Framework such that `5+6+7` is no longer `18`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just:

```
int sum = x.Where(i => i > 4).Sum();
```

If you call `ToArray`, that will copy all the data to a new array object, but if you don't need that, leave it out. `Sum` works on any `IEnumerable<int>` (and of other numeric types), no need to make an intermediate array there.

Anyway, *if* you call `ToArray`, you can leave out the `<int>` part as the compiler can **infer** the type argument, `int`, easily in this case.

When you do `Console.WriteLine`, you don't have to do `ToString` on the integer; `WriteLine` has an overload that takes in an `int` (no boxing), and it will call `ToString` automatically.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
int sum = x.Where(i => i > 4).Sum();
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to convert your filtered list to an intermediate array before you compute the sum. You can just do this:

```
int[] x = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7};
int sum = x.Where(i => i > 4).Sum();
Console.WriteLine(sum);
```

Now I wouldn't recommend this for production code because it's less readable, and it really doesn't improve performance in any meaningful way, but you could even do this with a single function call:

```
int[] x = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7};
int sum = x.Sum(i => i > 4 ? i : 0);
Console.WriteLine(sum);
```